# Handling parametric and reusable sprite animations

Tags: unity

I'd like to create a simple logic that handles sprite animations in a way that they can be easily reproduced and parametrized.
As example, I want to perform some basics animation like transitions and rotations and I like to have these animations receiving parameters as `x`, `y` and `angle` so that I can just attach the animation to gameObjects and set the parameters to obtain the needed animation.
I'm really new to Unity and I wonder if `Controller Animators` can handle this behaviour or if I have to go through animations off the `Transform` component properties. Is there any other way I'm not aware of to parametrize animations?

Comment: Take a look at [iTween](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/84). Its free and amazing :)

Comment: @HamzaHasan It seems it's not supported on unity 5

Comment: Who said? I'm using it. It will ask you to upgrade script accordingly. Just upgrade it. Thats it